# jquery get object value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get get the value `url` from this string:

```
[{
    "url": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WGS4Wmkk",
    "filename": "4827889.jpg",
    "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
    "size": 53113,
    "key": "be7BxONVHe_48278891840.jpg",
    "isWriteable": false
}]
```

With jquery or regular javascript

Comment: Did you mean for that code to be an array containing an object? It's kinda scrunched up, and it doesn't have quotations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `str` is the string you posted above, you can use JSON to parse it:

```
var data = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(data[0].url); // the url value
```

Comment: And the jQuery version: `var data = $.parseJSON(str);`